# converting NSMutableData to NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone

i am accumulating data from NSMutableDictionary to NSMutabledata like

```
    NSMutableData *data = [receivedData objectForKey:@"tag1"];
```

and also

```
    data  = [receivedData objectForKey:@"tag2"];
```

after this one , how can i get data for @"tag2" only from NSMutableData?

```
 NSMutableData tag2Data = [Data forKey:@"tag2"];
```

is not working?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you asking exactly? There is no 'forKey:' method on NSMutableData...

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure exactly what you are trying to do here, but it doesn't look like you are using the proper class. If you check the class reference from Apple there is a link to a [great code example](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingMutableData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002150) of getting a string out of an NSMutableData object, but the only way to access the data inside it is using getBytes.